# Using LineageOS native SSHD over ADB

Tags: adb, shell, ssh, services, lineageos

Ive got most of the way to getting native sshd working over usb (mainly for shell and winscp), but very murky and not quite there yet. I want to use the built-in sshd, not download an app for it.

Lineageos has a built-in SSHD and ADB allows forwarding from local host:XXXX to the phone on port 22. I've got a `sshd_config` file ready (password for now, RSA later), and Terminal + su all working. By trial and error I've found the sshd-start or start-sshd files and I'm probably most of the way there. But its hard to reproduce a trial and error approach and I haven't actually got it there yet.

The furthest I've got is that I can run ssh (client) on the phone and it'll at least try to connect to itself (in another terminal window), but doesn't yet fully reach a shell prompt. It gave errors on /var/run/etc and on missing an 'empty' dir which I manually created and seem to help but I don't really know if that's the right or best way to do it.

Assuming I have a valid config file and a clean install with no changes, what are the basic steps from the start, so.I can enable native sshd, start/stop it manually (not started with system), and access it across adb?

I would like to use /sdcard/sshdata for any keys/config, so they are preserved across installing, and for the moment, password over adb via usb only (not WiFi). I'm happy to mod some sshd-related files in /system and probably need to, but I don't know which I need to change.

What is the simplest recipe to get sshd available so that I can fire it up and connect when needed?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK with LineageOS 14.1 (I have a **rooted** FairPhone 2), `sshd` is enabled by default and ready to use. Its config file is `/system/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which points to `/data/ssh/` for keys storage. I guess you can reconfigure it to use `/sdcard/`. In *theory*, `/data` should be preserved across system updates, though I have not much experience to confirm it. The daemon needs to be started manually (this also generates the server's key pair; note that the `start-ssh` doesn't launch `sshd` in the background, hence the `&`):

```
$ adb root
phone # /system/bin/start-ssh &
```

Alternatively, you might want to configure another `sshd` instance as [explained here](http://lisas.de/~alex/?p=237).

To have `sshd` start at each boot (I still haven't tried), one option is to use [Termux:Boot](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux.boot/). Be aware that having a daemon always running might drain your battery!

As for running ADB and SSH, you say

> ADB allows forwarding from local host:XXXX to the phone on port 22

It is my understanding that this is not correct (unless you mean [forwarding from a dev machine to another host which the phone is tethered to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278429/how-to-set-up-adb-for-remote-machine-development-and-local-device-deployment)), as I don't see how `adbd` can handle encrypted connections. A quick sniff test with `ngrep` shows that my Wi-Fi connection on port 5555 is clear text.

Otherwise, make sure (I guess you already know it, but *repetita iuvant*...) that on your phone

1. `Developer options` are [enabled](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options)
2. `Developer options -> Root access` is set to "ADB" or "Apps ADB"
3. `Developer options -> ADB over network` is enabled

Then, on your computer terminal, the following command should get you on the go:

```
$ adb connect <your-android-host-name>
$ adb shell
```

...expect an excruciatingly slow, *not encrypted* connection :-(

Comment: `To have sshd start at each boot (I still haven't tried), one option is to use Termux:Boot` so there is no native auto-start for SSHD in Lineage?

Comment: @Suncatcher, AFAIK, nope! This still

Comment: (ouch, broken connection) ...still the case with LOS17.1